# Save Word HTML document as "Word Document"

Tags: coldfusion, ms-word, ms-office

I have reports which are written in "Word HTML" then served to users as a normal Word document (.doc) via `content-type="application/msword"`. However, when a user attempts to "Save As ..." one of these reports, Word automatically defaults the "Save as type:" to "Web Page". Is there a way to change it so that Word will default to "Word Document" when saving?

I am using ColdFusion running on Ubuntu to serve up the reports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you probably know, `<cfcontent>` simply changes the MIME type of the HTTP response, it does not change the data being returned at all. So given you've sent HTML data, that is how Word will treat it.

If you want Word to treat the doc as a native Word doc, you need to *send it* a native Word doc.

I've got no experience in doing this, but you might want to look at what [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/document/) offers by way of creating native Word docs. Alternatively Microsoft offer an API for doc creation / manipulation (cannae find a link, sorry), which would be something else to look at.

Comment: I've got experience of using POI for both Word and Excel. It'll do search/replace and will let you extensively modify documents, so you can almost certainly create your report. I will say that POI for Word is more flaky than POI for Excel and you'll almost certainly have to use JavaLoader to make use of the latest versions, but it certainly can be done.